# Bootstrap Menu Collapse Disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

#### Hello all,

I am trying to make a navbar disappear after being clicked (It also has a sub menu dropdown). I tried using this (in fact it worked for a while but now does not). Any help would be appreciated, David

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    <!--Make the menu collapse on option click in mobile mode-->
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery(".nav .dropdownmenu, .navbar-header .dropdownmenu").click(function(event) {
            // check if window is small enough so dropdown is created
           jQuery(".navbar-collapse").removeClass("in").addClass("collapse");
                });
        });

</script>
```

This is the dropdown menu

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" >
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a  href="index.html"><img  src = "images/logo.png" height="30px" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 5px;"></a>

        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdownmenu active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdownmenu"><a href="#salesSection">Sales</a></li>
            <li class="dropdownmenu"><a href="#lettingsSection">Lettings</a></li>
            <li class="dropdownmenu"><a href="#financeSection">Financial Services</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Branches <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdownmenu" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#northwichModal"><a >Northwich</a></li>
                <li class="dropdownmenu" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#middlewichModal"><a href="#">Middlewich</a></li>
                <li class="dropdownmenu" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#winsfordModal"><a href="#">Winsford</a></li>
                <li class="dropdownmenu" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lettingsModal"><a href="#">Northwich Lettings</a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Works fine **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/vw6eehuj/)**